# Механизм оповещения пользователей

Tags: php, mysql

Хочу сделать оповещение пользователей с подтверждением о прочтении.
Придумал только такой механизм:

Таблица сообщений:

`id|text`

Служебная таблица:

`message_id|user_id|date`

Т.е. для подтверждения прочтения нужно создавать запись в БД. А если пользователей несколько сотен тысяч?

Есть ли какие-то более оптимальные механизмы для такого дела?

Comment: Сделайте флажек, 1 - не прочитано, 0 - прочитано или наоборот.

Comment: К сожалению вы правы, в реляционных БД это практически единственно верный способ. таблица с как минимум 2 полями id сообщения и id пользователя. Более оптимальные решения могут быть основаны например на хранении диапазонов id пользователей в одной записи и одного поля bigint в котором каждый бит отвечает за прочитанность одним пользователем (хотя это уже нарушает НФ, но если хотите оптимально иногда про НФ надо забыть)

Comment: @And И как этот флажок будет работать, если сообщение одно, а пользователей много ... в какую таблицу этот флажок помещать

Comment: Как вариант, если считается, что пользователь читает все сообщения как только вошел в режим чтения, отмечать на сообщении дату публикации, а у пользователя хранить дату последнего чтения сообщений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Варианта два:

1) Сделать так как Вы описали, через дополнительную таблицу. В таком случае при большом количестве пользователей будет очень много записей.

2) Добавить ещё одно поле в таблицу с сообщениями, в котором будут храниться сериализированные данные с id пользователей, которые прочитали или не прочитали сообщение. При выборе этого варианта не будет кучи дополнительных записей, но усложнится поиск.

Comment: А для второго варианта нормально вообще хранить сериализованные данные? Особенно если если будет массив из нескольких сот тысяч элементов.

Comment: Вполне, можете использовать `BLOB`/`LONGBLOB`/`MEDIUMBLOB`